# React Link Doesn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I just started to learn react js and created a sample app, in which application has header, footer with content. To add header footer on each page I created root.js and include header, footer there. 
as props.children can render each nested route I added `{this.props.children}` inside root.js.

But When I clicked on any Links, nothing is happening, previous page(home) still rendered.

I could not understand whats going on and how to resolve this. Please help me, It already took me 2 days searching on google.

**Edit**:

Now working fine. Problem was that I added links inside

But now another problem is happening.
whenever I refresh page everything has gone. **pages are not found** shows

**Edit**:

Now working after page refresh by adding these line in

```
package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Home } from "./pages/home/index.jsx";
import { Root } from "./component/layout/root";
import { Blog } from "./pages/blog/index.jsx";
import { About } from "./pages/about/index.jsx";
import { Contact } from "./pages/contact/index.jsx";
import { Portfolio } from "./pages/portfolio/index.jsx";
import { Services } from "./pages/services/index.jsx";
import { Match } from 'react-router'; 
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {IndexRoute, browserHistory, Switch } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Root>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/blog" component={Blog}/>
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio}/>
                        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                        <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
                        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    </Switch>
                </Root>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

render( <App /> , window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**root.js**

```
import React  from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Header } from './header/index';
import { Footer } from './footer/index';

export class Root extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
    }

    render(){
        return( 
            <div>
                <Header/>
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Components**:

```
/blog/index.jsx
/home/index.jsx
/contact/index.jsx




import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";

export class Contact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
    < div id = "fh5co-contact-section" > 
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center fh5co-heading">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>
                <span>Created with
                    <i className="sl-icon-heart"></i>
                    by the fine folks at
                    <a href="http://freehtml5.co">FreeHTML5.co</a>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
            <h3>Contact Info.</h3>
            <ul className="contact-info">
                <li>
                    <i className="sl-icon-map"></i>198 West 21th Street, Suite 721 New York NY 10016</li>
                <li>
                    <i className="sl-icon-phone"></i>+ 1235 2355 98</li>
                <li>
                    <i className="sl-icon-envelope-open"></i>
                    <a href="#">info@yoursite.com</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i className="sl-icon-globe-alt"></i>
                    <a href="#">www.yoursite.com</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 col-md-push-1 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-0">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input className="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <textarea
                                    name=""
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id=""
                                    cols="30"
                                    rows="7"
                                    placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input value="Send Message" className="btn btn-primary" type="submit"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
export const Header = (props) => {
    return(
        <header id="fh5co-header" role="banner">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="header-inner">
                <h1><i className="sl-icon-energy"></i><Link to="/">Lesser</Link></h1>
                <nav role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link className="active"  to="/">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link  to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
                        <li><Link  to="/portfolio">Portfolio</Link></li>
                        <li><Link  to="/services">Services</Link></li>
                        <li><Link  to="/about">About</Link></li>
                        <li><Link  to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    );
};
```

Comment: Now all links working fine, But whenever I refresh page, it says page not found pages.

Comment: I am also using link inside router. How to separate them?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `Link` from `react-router-dom`:
`import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';`

and then use this `<Link to='url'>display text</Link>`

Comment: I added this, Now working fine. Problem was that  I added links inside <Router></Router>. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any links in your post but in any case you have to use the NavLink component from React-Router-Dom and replace any anchor tags with it.

Example:

```
<NavLink to="/blog">Blog</NavLink>
```

instead of:

```
<a href="/blog">Blog</a>
```

also for sake of readability and clean code it is better to seperate sections into components, form in its own component, contact info in its own and so on

Comment: Yes, I already added this, Now working fine. Problem was that I added links inside <Router></Router>.  Thanks.
Can I ask you? whenever I refresh page everything gone. pages are not found shows.